# Create child record using flow based on change of a pick list value

Tags: automation, flow

I would like to be able to create a comment whenever the value of a picklist field is changed (and the case record is saved). How can I achieve this using Flow?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, if you have the Flow Triggers for Workflow functionality enabled, which is currently in pilot.

https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=creating_workflow_flow_actions.htm&language=en_US